# How do I change errorbar & cap thickness in Seaborn 0.9.0

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting multiple ANOVA studies and I would like my error bar width and their cap thickness to be less than the trend line. When plotting a 3-way ANOVA, with error bars and caps, it can feel crowded. My current plot looks somethings like this:
[image: 3-Way Anova, uniform thickness]

My function for plotting this is:

```
sns.catplot(x="dose", y="somethings", hue="position", kind="point", 
        palette=sns.xkcd_palette(colors), capsize=.15, data=df, aspect=1.5)
```

I have tried to include keywords such as `lw_conf` (https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/898), but I'm not sure what happened to it's functionality after factorplot was changed to catplot. I have also tried errorbar keywords from matplotlib such as, `elinewidth` and `capthick`. Catplot seems to take `capsize` as a keyword argument but I don't know what other keywords it might take or what happened to `lw_conf`. Any feedback about what may have happened to that keyword or a new way of accomplishing this task would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`catplot` passes extra kwargs to the underlying plotting function. Since you are using `kind="point"`, the plotting function is `sns.pointplot()`. [The documentation for that function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot) mentions the parameter:

> **errwidth** : float, optional
>
> Thickness of error bar lines (and caps).

Therefore you only need to include `errwidth=` in your call to `catplot`:

```
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", kind="point", 
            capsize=.15, data=exercise, aspect=1.5, errwidth=0.5)
```

[image]